# End of semester farewell/thanks to teacher

Tags: set-phrases

We are approaching the end of this semester at my school. What is a good way to say thank you to my teacher?

「お世話になりましてありかとうございました。」 ?

Are there any other suggestions/additions?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to express your gratitude in one sentence, that is a very good one --- except, it is ありがとう, not ありかとう.