# Thank you note to Japanese professor

Tags: politeness, culture, written-language

I just finished an introductory Japanese class, and the class bought a small gift for the professor. I'm planning to drop the gift off at the professor's office, so I need to write a brief tag saying who it's from: "Thank you from the whole class." Is something as simple as:

ありがとうございます!

---[class name] のみな

correct and appropriate for the situation?

Comment: A related question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13616/1478

Comment: Thanks, @snailboat, I noticed that earlier. Is that a better formula to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

> [一年間]{いちねんかん}/[半年間]{はんとしかん}/[三ヶ月間]{さんかげつかん}etc.* お世話になり、ありがとうございました。
>   (class name)[一同]{いちどう} or (class name)一同より

*一年間=for a year, 半年間=for half a year, 三ヶ月間=for three months

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much (and for adding the kana)! We did cover units of time and the corresponding counters in class, but I haven't run into いちどう before. It looks like it means 'all of us', and it doesn't require a particle--- is that right?

Comment: @anomaly Right, 一同 can be 'all of (us/staff/group, etc.)', and you can use it like クラス一同(all of class), 生徒/学生一同(all the students), ３組一同(everyone in class 3), スタッフ一同(all the staff), etc.

Comment: Great, thanks again! I'm sure the professor will be happier to get a properly-written note. :)

Comment: This is a great answer. On that note, given how it's an introductory class, your professor probably wouldn't mind you using what you've been taught, even if it wasn't quite the right or best way to phrase it.